# Ruby github api not sending same response as irb?

Tags: ruby, irb, github-api

When I run the following snippet of Ruby code in RubyMine, it responds with `#<Github::Search:0x38d5b52>`.   However, when I run it in the irb shell, it responds appropriately with a large `JSON` object which is what I'm looking for.  Anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
require 'github_api'

github= Github.new do |config|
config.endpoint = 'http://my.domain.com/api/v3'
config.site= 'http://github.com'
config.adapter = :net_http
end

puts github.repos.search("pushed:2014-06-20")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IRB, the console is automatically calling `#inspect` on all returned objects.  This often times confuses developers who are new to Rails, for example, who are led to believe that queries can't be chained together because they see `#inspect` being called, causing the query to execute.

My guess is that you're witnessing the same thing here.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Do you know how to call inspect so that I can view the object?

Comment: In IRB, this is already happening automatically.  If you want to see the same in RubyMine, just call inspect on the returned object.  For example, `@search.inspect`.

Comment: I tried `github.search.repos('pushed:2014-06-14').inspect` and it is returning `#<Github::ResponseWrapper @body="#<Hashie::Mash items=[] total_count=0>">`.  Any ideas on what may be happening?

Comment: I mean, there should be no reason that you'd get two different responses.  What happens if you call `github.search.repos('pushed:2014-06-14').class` in IRB and in RubyMine?  They should return the same thing.

Comment: It returns `Github::ResponseWrapper`

Comment: If you're getting a Github::ResponseWrapper in both, and you really want the JSON representation of it, then you might be able to call `github.search.repos('pushed:2014-06-14').body`, which will return the body of the response to the API call.

Comment: Ahh, it turns out that I needed double quotes around the search string!

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.  The only difference between a single quoted string and a double quoted string is that a double quoted string can be interpolated with `#{}`, along with some other escape character differences.  But if that worked for you, good!

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make much sense to me either.  However, I'm very new to Ruby.  I appreciate the help!